# how to sort directories and files in a certain directory?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am reading all the directories and files inside a directory and want to sort the files alphabetically.

```
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      $files = array($file);
      sort($files);

      $clength = count($files);
      for($x = 0; $x < $clength; $x++) {
        echo $files[$x];
        echo "<br>";
      }
```

Code above outputs me all the directories and files but does not sort them alphabetically. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use this one.

```
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {


        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            $files[] = $file;

        }
        sort($files);
        $clength = count($files);
        for ($x = 0; $x < $clength; $x++) {
            echo $files[$x];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
```

### Update

```
$files[] = strtolower($file); // for ignore first letter capital
```

Comment: I'm so glad happy coding :)

Comment: Why `sort()` on each iteration?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, you need to first collect all the files and then sort them at once. So your code would look like-

```
<?php

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      $files[] = $file;
}

sort($files);
```

- But, a better options is to just use [scandir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) which returns you a list of files(including folders) in your directory and then you could sort them accordingly.
- I have used [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which sort files in alphabetical order ignoring upper case or lower case while preserving the original representation of the file name.

**Code:**

```
<?php 

$files = array_diff(scandir(YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH_HERE),array(".",".."));

usort($files,function($file1,$file2){
    return strcmp(strtolower($file1),strtolower($file2));
});

print_r($files);
```

- I have used [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to remove the `.` and `..` which is included in the result of `scandir().`

Comment: I used to sort them with `scandir` first, but I am rendering a lot of files. I compared `opendir/readdir` with `scandir` and the first one is much faster when it comes to render a lot of files. That's why I choose not to use `scandir` anymore

Comment: @mudrayakatusha Both should be more or less same performance wise because both have to read all files in a directory. Also, what do you mean by `render a lot of files`? Is this what you are building, kind of a file manager for some app?

Comment: yes. I it is for a filesystem. Maybe you are right about the performance of both, but I changed to use `opendir/readdir` based on this: https://infinitemonkey.xyz/software-development/scanning-a-directory-with-thousands-of-files/?unapproved=4&moderation-hash=2cf7191a2d8a0067e129605fd0e7ec07

Comment: @mudrayakatusha ok, I haven't tested this, so can't say anything now. Also updated my code with `array_diff` as it is a better option than `array_slice`.